# Search page changes through SP Designer only visible to Site Collection Admins

Tags: sharepoint-designer

The search bar on my search results page was showing up in the breadcrumb area in Sharepoint 2010 so I've moved a content block to the Main area instead.

The search bar properly shows up in the main area now when I'm using a Site Collection Admin account but it still shows up in the breadcrumb bar for regular users. It's like the changes haven't been saved. I've saved and checked in the changed pages.

Update: The search pages that I've edited have been checked in and published.

Why aren't regular users able to see the changes? Are there any other pages that need to be checked in so regular users can see the changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have the pages been approved/published?

Comment: Yes as far as I can tell they've been approved and published.

Comment: My master page hadn't been approved. I went into Site Settings -> Manage Content and Structure and saw that it hadn't been approved yet. When I was on the page itself it didn't show anything about not being approved. Thanks!